# Pull the first image from a Tumblr photoset?

Tags: tumblr

I'm designing a theme for a wedding photographer who wants to use Tumblr's Photoset functionality to create a portfolio site.

How do I pull the first image from a photoset so I can create a home page with a single thumbnail preview (sized to my choosing) that links to each set?

Thanks,
Parri

Comment: You might want to check out this source code for the Effector theme. It creates a slideshow from photosets starting with the first image. [link](http://pastie.org/1497762)

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a way to limit them, but you can *comment them out*. This solution has the advantage that **the hidden images won't be loaded at all** and **it doesn't need any javascript**

```
{block:Photoset}
    <!-- Go through each Photo in the Photoset -->
    {block:Photos}
        <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
        <!--
    {/block:Photos}
    -->

    {block:Caption}
        <p>{Caption}</p>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

See that `<!--` before `{/block:Photos}`? That opens an HTML comment right after the first image, so the rest of the images in the loop will be in a comment, invisible. After the loop we close the comment with `-->`. Done, all the images in the photoset after the first one will be hidden.

Comment: Very nice! This solution addresses issues with the two answers above yours: It doesn't load anything after the first photo, and doesn't require JavaScript. Plus it's much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 3):

**Tumblr markup:**

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="photoset-wrap">
    {block:Photos}
        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" />
    {/block:Photos}
    </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

*Note:* may be you need `{PhotoURL-75sq}` to output square preview instead of 500px image;

**CSS:**

```
.photoset-wrap img { display: none; }
.photoset-wrap img:first-child { display: block; }
```

Comment: +1 for answer, but i'm getting issues when trying to add link to post

Comment: @SaqibSaud describe your problem in details

Comment: its working in above scenario.

but not working for this one 
`
    {block:Photoset}
    <div class="photoset-wrap">
    
        {block:Photos}
    <a href="{Permalink}" >
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" />
    </a>
        {/block:Photos}
    
    </div>
    
    {/block:Photoset}
`

Comment: @SaqibSaud Do you want to transform the whole photoset with bunch of image to a link? In alone Photo post it is accepted usage of `<a/>` tag (because of only one element in link), but not for photoset

Comment: Thanks @vladimir-starkov Im getting your point, then how is it possible to add a link to photoset while only displaying single image?

Comment: @SaqibSaud it is another problem, create new question; comments are quite uncomfortable way of finding solutions

Answer (score 3):

the above example is flawed as the user has to download all the images even though only the first is shown so instead I've used jquery to inject only the first image.

HTML (simplified):

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="photoset">
        {block:Photos}
            <div class="photoPlaceholder" imgsrc="{PhotoURL-500}"></div>
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>
{block:Photoset}
```

javascript (simplified):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".photoset .photoPlaceholder").first().each(function (i) {
        var src = $(this).attr("imgsrc");
        $(this).html('<a href="#"><img src="'+ src +'" /></a>');
    });
});
```

This ensures only the first image is loaded... you can always have the other css example above in a noscript tag incase they have javascript turned off.

Hope that helps