# Displaying the first photo from the photoset on the index page

Tags: tumblr

I am trying to modify this theme, http://kcwork.tumblr.com/, I want just the first picture from the photoset to appear on the index page. can't seem to figure it out. if anyone could help, I would be very grateful. thank you. I know you have already answered similar question. but in my case I can't figure it out at all. I have already spent 8-10 hours since yesterday trying to figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull the first image from a Tumblr photoset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197453/pull-the-first-image-from-a-tumblr-photoset)

Comment: And another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296166/first-image-only-from-photoset-on-indexpage-then-all-on-permalinkpage/16306287#16306287